# Superscripting any Letter/Number for comma

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, superscript

I am getting some problem while getting below output.

**Expected OutPut** :

a<sup>2,3</sup> = a\u00B2\u066B\u00B3

**Actual Output :**

a<sup>2</sup>,<sup>3</sup> = a\u00B2\u066B\u00B3

Kindly review my question and reply soon.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no Superscript comma in Unicode.

However there are :

- Superscript plus sign (U+207A): `⁺`
- Superscript minus sign (U+207B): `⁻`
- Superscript equals sign (U+207C): `⁼`
- Superscript left parenthesis (U+207D): `⁽`
- Superscript right parenthesis (U+207E): `⁾`

Maybe you can use some other glyph, like the "dot operator" (U+22C5) to simulate a superscript comma: `¹⋅³²`.

You can also, of course, use `NSAttributedString` with a smaller font-size and an up-shifted baseline offset to simulate superscripting. However `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName` is only available starting with iOS 7.